# Background image wont show up

Tags: html

I have a background image that I want to repeat across (repeat-x) however when I try to view the page, nothing shows up. I'm also using javascript to use a different CSS file for different times of the day, however I am sure that is not the problem because firebug shows that the CSS file was added to the head.

Edit: The problem is that the browser cannot find the file, however when I attempt to link to it, it still cannot find the file.

You can download the archive of the site here:
`http://cdn.duffcraft.net.adam543i.net/sitebkp-1845.zip`
Its only 200 or so kb. Nothing massive.

Comment: not sure what firebug does in terms of resource checking, but in Chrome you can see if the url path (in resources tab) points to a valid file. Perhaps the browser cannot locate your background image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And you are sure the path to your image file is correct? Does Firebug load the image?

Your file structure is probably like this

```
index.html
css/
    style.css
img/
    night/
        night-tile.png
```

Now, from your `style.css` you have to use a relative path to your image file. So not `img/night/night-tile.png` but `../img/night/night-tile.png`. In your path it is looking for the image within the `css` directory, which is wrong.

**==Update==**

After downloading your code I found 2 more errors.

The first is that you forgot to add `rel=stylesheet` to the `<link>` element in which you link to your stylesheet. This way, browsers will not know it's a stylesheet.

The second is that you forgot to add a `;` at the end of your first rule in your `night.css`, resulting in a parse error which causes the background rule not to be rendered.

Good luck fixing these issues!

Comment: I guess you can look up the path on your machine / the server, no?

Comment: I can, but it doesn't seem to work. I'll zip the site and give you the link.

Comment: Have you tried the other tips as well? Your header should have some height before you can use a background (image or color).

Comment: Yeah, I have, but none of them seemed to help.

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that, and I also added `rel=stylesheet` to it and works now. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 2):

As there is no text in your header the div will not get displayed.Try following css

```
#header {
    background-image:url(img/night/night-time-tile.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    position:absolute;
    height:100px;  // Adjust height according to your image height 
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Chrome browser, inspect the element where the background image should appear.

Hover over the background-image declaration in the firebug window

```
background-image:url(img/night/night-time-tile.png);
```

and you will see the full path of the image.

In the screenshot you can see the equivalent for the stackoverflow logo at the top of the page.

You can then click on the css declaration and change the url until you find the correct path for your image.

[image]

Comment: This helped me a lot. I ended up having to change the file name, and then it worked. I have no clue why, but it works now. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The element has no height (either explicit or from content).

This means there are no visible pixels of the element to see the image across.